# How do i read a particular file line using a giving unique id not the line number

Tags: php, file

Am trying delete user chat based on selected message, but i don't know how i can read the line without using the line number because i used php file to store the chat conversation for security and i also added a php code on first line of each php file containing the chat to prevent direct access.

I have a file name `conversation.php`

```
 lineid  | user | message | deleted
---------|------|---------|-----------
100      | joe  | HI      | NO
101      | pee  | Hello   | NO
103      | kik  | Hmm     | NO
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['deletechatroomid']) && isset($_POST['messageline'])){
    $chatsession = xss_protextion("char", $_POST['deletechatroomid']); /*Chat Path ID*/
    $messageline = xss_protextion("int", $_POST['messageline']); /*Chat Line ID*/

    $filePathname = dirname(__FILE__).'/chatlogs/'.$chatsession.'/conversation.php'; /*FULL FILE PATH*/


    /*
   I know that i i can identify the line number below code will get it for me but i don't want to use it because the it might delete another chat if mistak line id
   $getDeleteLine = file( $filePathname ); 
    echo $getDeleteLine[67];
   */
    }
    ?>
```

I can will i use the unique id of each chat line to read only the line?

Comment: Seems like something much better suited for a database than a text file

Comment: @PatrickQ yes i know it will be easy doing in database, i can still change to using database please please tell me does shared hosting has maximum record to store in each database table? and is using database more faster?

Comment: You will of course have to go through all lines and compare the line id with the value you are looking for, until you find it (or run out of lines.) Yes, because of your decision to implement a storage solution yourself you will now have to implement a lot of features yourself that f.e. a database has already on board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to process the entire file to retrieve the id you are looking for.

The only other solution would be some external storage which could give you the line number from the id. That would be called an index in the database world, giving @Patrick Q's suggestion in the above comment a lot of sense in your case : better use a database than a text file for your use case. SQLite is a lightweight one, give it a try.